# Cat5 Gigabit not working

Tags: ethernet, cable

I have an 8-pin cable running through my wall (from basement to first floor) which was probably an old phone cable, which I terminated with RJ45 plugs on each end - resulting in a Cat5 cable.

I tested it with a network cable tester and everything works fine. But when I plug it into my computer, I only get 100mbit/s instead of gigabit, which sucks because my internet is faster than this (I tried Powerline, but my internet connection is too fast/the distance is too far).

Why is gigabit not working? Thanks!

Comment: If it really is old phone cable, it probably has too much crosstalk to get Gigabit speeds.

Comment: @RonTrunk it is the only cable in the wall and also isolated, I don't think that this is the issue. But can I run it at above 100mbit/s but below gigabit?

Comment: The crosstalk is between the pairs, not other cables.  Your end devices negotiate the speed they can operate at.  If they can't do Gigabit, they will drop down to 100M.

Comment: @RonTrunk all devices are able to do gigabit.

Comment: You misunderstand me.  Your devices attempt to communicate at 1G.  If the cable has problems so they can't talk, they try a lower speed , 100M.

Comment: @RonTrunk is there anything I could do to prevent this?

Comment: The higher speed you go, the more exact the cabling  requirements are. From your description, it sounds like the problem is the cable (or your terminations).  You may have to replace it.  If that's not practical, you should consider wireless.

Comment: Just because you claim it is Category-5, doesn't make it so. Did you use an expensive tester to run the Category-5 test suite to see if it passed? Also, 1000BASE-T (gigabit) is specified for Category-5e and above.

Comment: Your business should spend a little money to get a cable installer to test and correct your cable problem. The 1000BASE-T (gigabit ethernet standard) requires all four pairs to be functional to certain specifications, and if they are not, it will try to drop down to 100BASE-TX (100 Mbps). The frequencies in play here really need an expert with the proper equipment.

Comment: So you are paying for 1gbps internet? Actually Gbps means Gigabits Per Second
And here, MBPS means Megabytes Per Second 1 byte = 8 bits 1000 Megabits = 128 Megabytes
Cut off 10% as traffic loss. It rounds off as 100 MBPS speed. That is very fine.
You are getting 1 Gbps speed but 1 Gbps is calculated in bits while the download speed is calculated in bytes. So you will get 1/10 of the written speed in every internet on earth. Hope that is clear.

Comment: @jackray I don't have gigabit internet. However, I am aware of the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheap cable testers will only tell you if there is continuity. They won't tell you anything about the high-speed performance of the cable.

The first question is is the cable actually CAT5 or is it some kind of telphone-grade cable. If it's not actually CAT5 then frankly you are lucky to be getting 100 megabit let alone gigabit.

The second question is whether the cable is terminated properly. Untwisting needs to be kept to a minimum and you need to ensure that there are no "split pairs".

Ultimately if the termination looks good then the cable is almost certainly either inadequate or faulty. Time for a new run of cable.